# How can I have linting features available on my IDE despite the project being on a docker container?

Tags: node.js, docker, visual-studio-code, docker-compose, eslint

I have a React Node.js project running on docker. I was able to make it work by following the article [here](http://jdlm.info/articles/2016/03/06/lessons-building-node-app-docker.html).

The problem is that `node_modules` folder on my host machine is empty. Changing the `volumes` to `/www/project/node_modules:app/node_modules` will render the modules unavailable in the docker container.

The workaround that I'm using is to install only the dependencies on my host machine by running `npm install --only=dev`. However, they disappear every time I restart the container.

Here is a copy of my [Github](https://github.com/abarcenas29/react-sandbox) repo that does this.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

So there are few things here, you need to deviate from that article. Because that articles uses anonymous volume for the `node_modules`. In your case you want the devDepencies to come to your host also, so you can use them.

Now Node will not allow two different folders for dependencies until your use `requirejs` module and configure multiple sources in that. So for your development image what you want is that `yarn` is not run inside the `Dockerfile`. Instead it is run when the container starts

So I will change the Dockerfile as

```
FROM node:7.10.1

ENV HOME=/home/app
COPY package.json $HOME/react/
COPY scripts $HOME/react/scripts/
RUN npm install yarn -g
WORKDIR $HOME/react
ENV NODE_PATH=/home/node_modules
VOLUME $NODE_PATH
CMD yarn start:dev
```

Then update `docker-compose.yml`

```
react:
  build: .
  ports:
   - 3100:3100
  volumes:
    - .:/home/app/react
    - ./node_modules:/home/node_modules
```

Now if you do `docker-compose up` the `node_modules` is empty. So what you should do whenever you want to refresh the packages

```
docker-compose run react yarn
docker-compose up -d
```

Using `NODE_PATH` we changed the location of `node_modules` to `/home/node_modules` inside the container. Then in `docker-compose` we mapped the same to `./node_modules` on host. So our first `docker-compose run react yarn`, will fill this folder with all the dependencies.

From next time you just run `docker-compose up`. Any time you want to update dependencies you either run "yarn" inside the `react` container or you just run the `docker-compose run ...` command again

Comment: This is brilliant!

Comment: The key line here really is: `what you want is that yarn is not run inside the Dockerfile. Instead it is run when the container starts`. Unfortunately, this does mean that you cannot take advantage of Docker caching that step and it will rerun each time you start your container.